# Extracting bits from std::stringstream to std::bitset

Tags: c++, stl, std

According to some documentation I found for `std::bitset`:

> They can also be directly inserted and extracted from streams in binary format (see applicable operators).

Applicable operators:

> is,os
>   basic_istream or basic_ostream object from which a bitset object is respectively extracted or inserted. The format in which bitsets are inserted/extracted is a sequence of (suitably widened) '0' and '1' characters.

```
template<class charT, class traits, size_t N>
   basic_istream<charT, traits>&
     operator>> (basic_istream<charT,traits>& is, bitset<N>& rhs);
 template<class charT, class traits, size_t N>
   basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
     operator<< (basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os, const bitset<N>& rhs);
```

This essentially means that we are allowed to do something like:

```
std::stringstream _stream(std::ios::binary);
{...}
std::bitset<16> a1;
std::bitset<8> a2;
_stream >> std::bin >> a1;
_stream >> std::bin >> a2;
```

It seems to me that I just **don't have** `std::bin` in the Standard Library, everything else should be ok.

I'm wondering if there is any way to implement this modifier?

Comment: What is `std::bin`? I've never heard of it.

Comment: What data is in your stream?  If it is a string of `1` and `0` this already works.

Comment: What the documentation you quoted means is that you can do `_stream >> a1;` _without_ any special IO manipulator like `std::bin` (which does not exist). However, the bitsets will be represented by 0s and 1s, stored as characters in the stream. I don't think there is any standard way to get them stored as actual bits.

Comment: Simply look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2) how to use it. And yes WTH is `std::bin`??

Comment: Sorry for confusing all(@remyabel, @Retired Ninja, @g-makulik ) of you, but I've mentioned that we **don't** have `std::bin` in the stl to make the dream come true. @jogojapan I have some binary-oriented data in my stream(let's say there is a binary file) but not prearranged zeroes and ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing like a `std::bin` stream manipulator, but If you want to write the `std::bitset` contents bit wise, you might try the following:

```
template<std::size_t num_bits>
void writeBits(ostream& os, const std::bitset<num_bits>& thebits)
{
    for(std::size_t bit_pos = 0; bit_pos < num_bits;)
    {
        unsigned char currentByte = 0;
        for(int currentBit = 0; 
            currentBit < sizeof(unsigned char) && 
            bit_pos < num_bits; 
            ++currentBit, ++bit_pos)
        {
            currentByte |= thebits[bit_pos] ? (0x80 >> currentBit) : 0;
        }
        os << currentByte;
    }
}
```

See the full sample on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Jc2IIY).

The other way round would only work if you know the size of `std::bitset<>` portions to read in advance:

```
template<std::size_t num_bits>
void readBits(istream& is, std::bitset<num_bits>& thebits)
{
    thebits.reset();
    std::size_t total_bytes = num_bits / sizeof(unsigned char) + 1;
    std::size_t bit_pos = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; 
        is && 
        i < total_bytes && 
        bit_pos < num_bits;
        ++i)
    {
        unsigned char currentByte = 0;
        if(is >> currentByte)
        {
            for(int currentBit = 0; 
                currentBit < sizeof(unsigned char) &&
                bit_pos < num_bits;
                ++currentBit, ++bit_pos)
            {
                thebits[bit_pos] = (currentByte &  (0x80 >> currentBit)) > 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the full sample on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Il9p30).